# PHP session won't save

Tags: php, session

I've seen similar questions here but none of the solutions work for me.
I am running php 5.6 in WAMP and localhost.
When the user logs in correctly, I start the session with `session_start()` and set `$_SESSION['user']`
to `$_POST['username']`, and then i use `header('Location: home.php')`.
home.php starts with `session_start()` function, and then i check if the `$_SESSION['user']` is set. If it isn't, I redirect to the login page. However, even when I log in with valid password and email, it always redirects me to the login page for reasons unkown. I tried to `echo` the `$_SESSION['user']`, but it just says that it's undefined. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: you have to start session before user login

Comment: please write your code here so we can fix it and explain what have you done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually put `session_start();` at the `header.php`, The problem now is that you've assigned `$_POST['username']` to a `session`, Which is wrong, We use the `$_POST['']` to retrieve data from the `database`, So you have to type your `SELECT` query and get the username from `username row` inside the `database` then assign the `row` data to a session like this `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];`

So in brief, Your mistake is using `$_POST['username']` instead of `SELECT`ing the data from your `database` using `$_POST` then assigning it as `session` like this `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
include('dbconnect.php'); //php with server connection detail
session_start();

$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$user_check' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_session = $row['username'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. maybe you cannot set 'session_auto_start = on' in php.ini
2. First check the php.ini session_save_path in existence, and there is no comment out if there are general default in Widnows is c:\windows\tmp, the directory is not allowed to read other users by default.and Set folder for everyone to read writable

Answer (score 0):

make sure your php.ini file have `session.autostart = On`

If you're using apache, and have the right Options, you can enable `session.auto_start` with a `.htaccess` file containing this line: php_flag `session.auto_start 1`

do `session_start()` on the top of everything.